# bluetooth serial port not visible

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port

I'm trying to establish Bluetooth communication between my desktop (Win XP) and my handheld device (Blackberry Bold OS6.0). I defined a Bluetooth serial port (COM10) on my desktop and querying it does show it, but I'm unable to locate it from my handheld. When initiating device discovery from the handheld the desktop is visible but the only service exposed seems to be the headphones.

Any guesses on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define it as "Incoming" or "Outgoing"?  (That's assuming that your PC uses the Microsoft Bluetooth stack and not Widcomm etc).  What are you "querying it" with?

Comment: It's a Widcomm. I'm using the BluetoothSerialPort.getSerialPortInfo() of the RIM Blackberry Bluetooth API to retrieve all visible serial ports, but it's only returning the one for ActiveSynch.

Comment: Is there a program running with COM10 open?  (Did you click Auto-Start on the Widcomm 'add' dialog?)

Comment: Yeah, I did check autostart. It works now for some reason, I swear I didn't change anything. Maybe it's because I restarted the computer. Thanks for your help!